# How do select a shape which is inside the boundary of another shape in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am not able to select a shape which is inside the boundary of another shape, I mean only outer shape gets selected. If a shape is partially inside another shape , I can select it clicking the mouse outside the boundary of bigger shape.
But for its possible that a shape can fall under another shape and need to select it.

```
<!--fabricjs event function-->
     canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e){
        console.log('over1',e.target)
        if(e.target && e.target!= canvas.getActiveObject()){
                 canvas.setActiveObject(e.target);
           }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select it by setting each object "perPixelTargetFind" property to true at the time of adding it to canvas.

obj.perPixelTargetFind = true;